# Why does my network set my hostname? How can I stop this?

Tags: macos, mac, dns, hostname

(I'm using a Mac. It triple boots OS X.8, Gentoo, and Windows 7. I've only noticed the problem in OS X, but that's what I use most of the time so it might be occurring in other OSes.)

I've used System Preferences to set my host name to what I want it to be. Yet, when I connect to particular networks (parent's house, dorms, school, etc), as far as Darwin is concerned, my hostname becomes something else. I say Darwin because Terminal and the sharing panels in System Preferences ('Other users can [some sharing action] your computer [some address involving the altered hostname]'). Sometimes the altered hostname is a lower case version of what it should be, sometimes its host1234.some.provider.com, or just host1234.

This frustrates me. I want my hostname to be what I set it to, always, across all systems. Especially in Mac. What can I do to prevent this alteration? I have (root) access to a server with BIND on it, so should I set up dynamic global hostname? Are there any guides to setting up BIND for that (RFC 3007)? I (mostly) understand DNS as applied to websites, etc, but I've only ever altered the bindings in CPanel.

UPDATE: I'm not complaining about clients showing fully qualified host names. My local machine is showing a different host name. Lets say my computer's hostname is set to be `Firelizzards-Computer` in OS X's equivalent of `/etc/hostname`. Right now, connected to my dorm's WiFi, running `hostname` returns `host-173-230-36-89.mycampusname.clients.myprovider.com` (my LAN address is `173.230.36.89`). Why is `hostname` not returning `Firelizzards-Computer.mycampusname.clients.myprovider.com`?

NOTE: The phrase ['dynamic global hostname'](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11259) refers to a setting in OS X that involves RFC 3007.

SOLUTION: `sudo scutil --set HostName <desired host name>`. I found [this](http://osxdaily.com/2012/10/24/set-the-hostname-computer-name-and-bonjour-name-separately-in-os-x/), [this](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~bhardie/misc/misc/scutil.html), and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66611/how-to-change-computer-name-so-terminal-displays-it-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion), the last one being my exact problem.

**So now my question is**, by what mechanism is connecting to a LAN changing what `hostname` was returning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer from Daniel J. is not a valid answer. It's just "stating a fact". Can it be done or not? And how is it done?

The answer is yes. Here is how:

- Go in your OSX Network preferences and select the network card you are connected with.
- Click on "Advanced..." near the bottom right corner of the dialog box (above "Assist me.." "Revert" and "Apply")
- In the new window that comes up, click on the WINS tab and change the NetBIOS Name and Workgroup to your liking.
- Save the changes ... et voilà

Comment: Do you need to set this for every WiFi network that you connect to?

Comment: I do not know. Give it a try and let us know please.

Comment: I ended up using `sudo scutil --set HostName {name}` (which is mentioned at the end of the question). It works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your computer is getting its hostname from a DHCP server. If you are in a campus context it is normal that network administrators try to keep control on any aspect that they can.